# How do I motivate my colleagues?

Tags: colleagues

Sometimes I have to work with a particular colleague on my team; the problem is, in my opinion, that he takes his work too lightly. When I start a job, I commit to it and want to meet my deadlines and provide a decent product (I'm a programmer).

My colleague just wants to make it work, but doesn't think about maintainability, documentation, etc. I feel like his attitude might affect our project and is the basis for some frustration.

How do I motivate him? How do I bring up that I don't like the way we are working at the moment?

Comment: So you're concerned about his motivation to make a *good* product, but he is getting his work done on time? It's an issue of the depth of his work then?

Comment: Since this is a team project I assume others have to read his code, right? Does anyone else maintain it? This is partly a matter of teamwork too.

Comment: Not yet, it's going to be done in a few weeks.

Comment: The program works, so any additional effort is politically founded.  In other words you need the organization to demand the extra work be a required part of any delivery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make it less about the work ethic (real or perceived), and make it about the task at hand, deliverables, and making sure the work meets your expectations. In order to do that, you'll need to communicate your expectations, from timelines to quality, to whatever else are the important criteria for you. These things take time and dedicated training.

You've identified the problem (the perceived gap in delivery quality, based on a set of criteria). Simply pointing it out to the other person won't fix it - you have to be clear when expectations are met, exceeded, and left wanting. Humans are pattern-matching creatures - co-workers generally pick up on things when the goals are well defined.

I could probably point you toward some more specific resources, if you want to be more specific about the kinds of challenges you're having with this individual. Quality/speed/delivery issues are common, but rather broad, and as a result, difficult to answer with a "silver bullet" approach. You really need to dig into the specifics if you want to make a lasting, and high-quality change in the people around you.

Comment: I think you mostly got it. You have to __be concrete__ about what's wrong with the work he's turning out, because he seriously may not get it otherwise.

Answer (score 16):

Far more important than trying to *motivate* people is help them by removing the barriers to them *motivating themselves*.

The reason for this is the difference between [intrinsic and extrinsic motivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation#Intrinsic_and_extrinsic_motivation).

From the Wikipedia page:

> *Intrinsic* motivation refers to motivation that is driven by an interest or enjoyment in the task itself, and exists within the individual rather than relying on any external pressure.
>
> *Extrinsic* motivation comes from outside of the individual. Common *extrinsic* motivations are rewards like money and grades, coercion and threat of punishment. Competition is in general *extrinsic* because it encourages the performer to win and beat others, not to enjoy the *intrinsic* rewards of the activity. A crowd cheering on the individual and trophies are also *extrinsic* incentives.

According to research, *intrinsic* motivators are much more powerful than *extrinsic* motivators:

> At lower levels of [Maslow's hierarchy of needs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs), such as physiological needs, money is a motivator, however it tends to have a motivating effect on staff that lasts only for a short period (in accordance with Herzberg's two-factor model of motivation).
>
> At higher levels of the hierarchy, praise, respect, recognition, empowerment and a sense of belonging are far more powerful motivators than money

Now while there is little evidence of *Maslow's hierarchy* itself, it is a useful hook when describing *intrinsic* verses *extinsic* motivators.

The *surprising thing* that comes out of the research though, is that providing *extrinsic* motivators can actually reduce or remove the *intrinsic* motivators:

> Social psychological research has indicated that *extrinsic* rewards can lead to overjustification and a subsequent reduction in *intrinsic* motivation. In one study demonstrating this effect, children who expected to be (and were) rewarded with a ribbon and a gold star for drawing pictures spent less time playing with the drawing materials in subsequent observations than children who were assigned to an unexpected reward condition and to children who received no *extrinsic* reward.<sup>1</sup>

1. [Undermining Children’s Intrinsic Interest with Extrinsic Reward; A Test of ‘Overjustification’ Hypothesis](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=Undermining%20Children%E2%80%99s%20Intrinsic%20Interest%20with%20Extrinsic%20Reward;%20A%20Test%20of%20%E2%80%98Overjustification%E2%80%99%20Hypothesis&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=zc01UfqWF8jMPZqYgaAF&ved=0CC4QgQMwAA), Lepper, Greene & Nisbett.

Thus, in general it is **far** more effective to remove barriers intrinsic motivation than it is to try an increase extrinsic motivators. This was the essence of many elements of both [DeMarco & Lister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_DeMarco)'s [Peopleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peopleware:_Productive_Projects_and_Teams) and [Fred Brooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Brooks)' [The Mythical Man-Month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month). These should be considered essential reading for any manager of software engineers, but could also help managers of other knowledge workers.

For more information, I would highly recommend [this animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6XAPnuFjJc) of one of [Daniel Pink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Pink)'s talks on his book "[Drive: The Surprising Truth About What Motivates Us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive:_The_Surprising_Truth_About_What_Motivates_Us)".*

Comment: To be fair, behavioral psychology would have it that you shouldn't tell the children in advance that they are to receive the ribbon for drawing pictures, but just do it. Over several trials, this should increase incidence of drawing. The study violated the tenets of behavior modification, so it is not surprising it produced those results.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - But that's precisely what they did. The study compared a group children who were told about the reward, a group children who were given no reward **and** a group children who were given an unexpected reward. I'll add a ref for the paper.

Comment: I hope you're not basing this conclusion on an article abstract.

Comment: @JeffO - I'm not a social scientist, so I don't know how much acceptable methodology has changed since '72, but the paper does appear to deal with Amy's point. Also, the results (table 1) do seem to match up with the assertion in the abstract, but I would be happy to edit into my answer any criticism you (or Amy) may have of the paper cited. By the way the quote is from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation#Intrinsic_and_extrinsic_motivation) page I referenced earlier in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

From what I can tell, it doesn't sound like your coworker is unmotivated or taking his work lightly, let alone that he doesn't want to meet deadlines or provide a decent product - he simply has a different idea of what that task includes than you do. (*"My colleague just wants to make it work, but doesn't think about maintainability, documentation etc."*)  This is a conversation you should probably have with him, but I don't think it will go very well if you come off as judgemental. Just phrase it as a disagreement on the best way to accomplish the tasks, and **discuss it from a practical standpoint** - how to satisfy the project requirements, what's easier when the whole team works on the code, what makes it easier to find bugs, etc - rather than getting involved in questions like who is or isn't properly motivated or taking the work seriously, which will only make it more difficult to accomplish anything.

Another possibility would be to take this up with management. What are *their* standards for maintainability, documentation, etc? If they don't have any, can you convince them to set some?

Talk to the rest of the team, too. How do they feel about the quality of his work? Have any of them tried to talk to him about it already, and if so, how did it go? You'll be in a much better position when it's not just you against him, but trying to agree on some team standards.

Answer (score -1):

I see this as a problem with your company structure on the first place, not a problem with your colleague.

The structure of your company obviously does not give you the freedom to decide who to work with. Moreover, if the situation is really the way you describe it, this restriction comes as a disadvantage to the company itself.

From this point of view you could:
a) ask your managers to change their policies so next time you choose your partner on a project or receive a budget to hire one yourself;

or

b) talk with your colleague about your standards of performance in a calm and constructive manner. Then proceed work and never fret if your colleague doesn't keep up to those standard. Ask for salary increase instead and do your part of the job top-notch and never care for the quality of the final product solely within the scope of your particular work. The rationale is that if your bosses insist on holding the power to decide who works with who, then, your professionalism should come at a price, given that they are actually sabotaging it.

Comment: Am I reading this right?  The options you suggest are: Choose who you work with, or ask for a raise if you don't get to choose?  I don't see that going over well in most places.

Comment: I started to agree with the company problem, but I don't think not being able to choose a capapble programmer to work with, but why is an incapable developer still with the company? Or maybe the Op's expectations and standards are higher than the company's?

Comment: @GreenMatt - you are right with one small amendment - "ask for a raise if you don't get to choose **someone better than the one you currently have to work with**" If I were in a perfectly selected team I wouldn't ask for a raise. The great team by itself would be an exceptional benefit. But if they were making me work with somebody mediocre, I would definitely seek a compensation for my extra efforts being put into an environment of low effort.

Comment: @ Jeff O - sorry, I couldn't get you

Comment: -1: To start: "... your professionalism should come at a price ..." is bad advice; it is best to be professional always. Also "... given that they are actually sabotaging it." is overstating what the question describes.  As my previous comment implied, I don't think it's good advice to demand to choose who you work with or be given a raise if you don't get that choice - no one is perfect and in my experience it is common to be required to work with someone I'd rather avoid for one reason or another.

Comment: @GreenMatt - what I had in mind by "should come at a price" is that one should value his professionalism and ask for a higher price when everybody around does not even seem to care. You create more value, you ask for more money in return.

Comment: A boss won't always be able to let you choose with whom you work because the organization may only have you and one other person with the expertise to do a particular job.  Giving you a raise to get you to work with someone you prefer to avoid will open the org up to the same demands from everybody.  The guy who you think is an unprofessional corner-cutter may think you're arrogant and more concerned about following dogma than getting the job done, so he'll want a raise.  Also, will you give up that raise when the project is over and you don't have to work with the undesirable person anymore?

Comment: @ GreenMatt - you have your points but what do they have to do with the original question? A person is asking how to be productive in a team with somebody else, not how to carry himself the company's woes. If the company finds it so hard to create the needed productive environment then they are just incapable and it is their problem. There is no reason why it should become the employee's problem (as it currently is). If he begins to fix (motivate) his co-worker, he would be actually doing the job of management and that is neither his competence nor does he get paid for that.

Comment: @ GreenMatt - "Also, will you give up that raise when the project is over and you don't have to work with the undesirable person anymore?" - yes, I would give it up.

Comment: @drabsv: You asked what my comments have to do with the OP's question.  My response is to observe that *your answer* has nothing to do with the question.  The question is about getting fellow employees to work more in line with the way the OP thinks they should work.  It said nothing about getting perks for yourself when working with someone you don't want to work with.  That's part of why I gave a -1.  My comments have been made because I think your suggestion is misguided and likely to cause trouble for someone following this advice.

Comment: @drabsv: As for giving up your increased salary:  it's nice that you would do so, but now (at least in your boss' viewpoint) you're basically making yourself into an internal contractor, with a potentially changing pay rate for every project.  One reason organizations hire employees is that they want cost predictability.  If they have to renegotiate costs with every employee for every project (which they'll have to do if they do it for one employee), they may as well fire everyone and just staff every project with contractors.

Comment: I certainly would not long retain an employee with this attitude.  Everyone has to sometimes work with people they would rather not. Anyone who wants a raise for that is a prima donna who my organization would be better off not employing.  And likely that person is not nearly as valuable as they think they are.